# How can users get bazel-run.sh?

Tags: bazel

`bazel run` typically occupies the Bazel server, blocking other commands.

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/c484f19a2cf7427887d6e4c71c8534806e1ba83e/scripts/bazel-run.sh is a fantastic replacement

Question: what's a good way for end-users to get hold of that shell script and add to their path? Can we make that part of the bazel install?

I tried `ls -R $(bazel info install_base) | grep bazel-run` but no luck there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bazel run is a good replacement for end-user to run a Bazel command if you need to run interactively or multiple command ([#2337](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2337)). There has been no need for us to consider it as an installation script.

Please file an issue on [Github](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues) to discuss the possibility of installing it along with Bazel.

Comment: Issue #2337 seems like the right way forward.
In the meantime I copied the important line of bazel-run.sh into my command runner